# How does regular expression engine parse regex with recursive subpatterns to match palindromes?

Tags: php, regex, recursion, pcre, palindrome

This regular expression matches palindromes:
`^((.)(?1)\2|.?)$`

Can't wrap my head around how it works.
When does the recursion end, and when regex breaks from the recursive subpattern and goes to `"|.?"` part?

edit: sorry I didn't explain `\2` and `(?1)`

`(?1)` - refers to first subpattern (to itself)

`\2` - back-reference to a match of second subpattern, which is `(.)`

Above example written in PHP. Matches both "abba" (no mid palindrome character) and "abcba" - has a middle, non-reflected character.

Comment: This would probably be better of in Programmers since this really isnt a "practical" question.

Comment: The `.?` is probably for odd-length strings.

Comment: Sorry, but may I know what's `(?1)` and `\2`?

Comment: Perl has better debugging tools than PCRE, try: `echo 123454321 | perl -Mre=debug -ne '/^((.)(?1)\2|.?)$/x'`

Comment: @AlvinWong: `(?1)`=recurse into group 1, `\2`=backreference to match from group 2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`^((.)(?1)\2|.?)$`

The `^` and `$` asserts the beginning and the end of the string respectively. Let us look at the content in between, which is more interesting:

```
((.)(?1)\2|.?)
1------------1 // Capturing group 1
 2-2           // Capturing group 2
```

Look at the first part `(.)(?1)\2`, we can see that it will try to match any character, and that same character at the end (back reference `\2`, which refers to the character matched by `(.)`). In the middle, it will recursively match for the whole capturing group 1. Note that there is an implicit assertion (caused by `(.)` matching one character at the beginning and `\2` matching the same character at the end) that requires the string to be at least 2 characters. The purpose of the first part is chopping the identical ends of the string, recursively.

Look at second part `.?`, we can see that it will match one or 0 character. This will only be matched if the string initially has length 0 or 1, or after the leftover from the recursive match is 0 or 1 character. The purpose of the second part is to match the empty string or the single lonely character after the string is chopped from both ends.

The recursive matching works:

- The whole string must be palindrome to pass, asserted by `^` and `$`. We cannot start matching from any random position.
- If the string is <= 1 character, it passes.
- If the string is > 2 characters, whether it is accepted is decided by the first part only. And it will be chopped by 2 ends if matches.
- The leftover if matches, can only be chopped by the 2 ends, or passes if its length is <= 1.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've edited the original post with more explanation. `\2` is not length.

Comment: `\2` is not length, but it does force that expression to be at least two characters long, because a single character can't match both `(.)` and the backreference `\2`.

Comment: Each time it recurses because of the first part, it's processing the string with the two end characters removed. Eventually it shrinks to 0 or 1 characters, then the second part matches and the recursion stops.

Comment: I do admit it is a bit confusing. I have edited my post, but I'm not sure if it is any clearer.

Comment: Answer accepted. Thank you! I admin I still have troubles comprehending it, perhaps I need to learn automata.
one more question: when a function calls itself, it goes "back" when it reaches "bottom" state (say, 1 in calculating factorial) and multiplies that by previous call results, but when is the finite state reached here? At what point, regex engine goes "now I go match "\2" in reverse order, one by one", if it makes sense?

Comment: @alexy2k: I don't know how the regex engine works. I imagine that it will stupidly go into recursion match `(?1)` first, then it will match `\2` (since in a general regex, you won't know if there are more recursive groups ahead). This is more of guessing, so don't take this comment too seriously.

Answer (score 4):

The regex is essentially equivalent to the following pseudo-code:

```
palin(str) {
    if (length(str) >= 2) {
      first = str[0];
      last = str[length(str)-1];
      return first == last && palin(substr(str, 1, length(str)-2));
    } else
      // empty and single-char trivially palindromes
      return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found any nice debugging utility for PCRE regexps. The more I could find was how to dump the bytecode:

```
$ pcretest -b
PCRE version 7.6 2008-01-28

  re> /^((.)(?1)\2|.?)$/x
------------------------------------------------------------------
  0  39 Bra
  3     ^
  4  26 CBra 1
  9   6 CBra 2
 14     Any
 15   6 Ket
 18   6 Once
 21   4 Recurse
 24   6 Ket
 27     \2
 30   5 Alt
 33     Any?
 35  31 Ket
 38     $
 39  39 Ket
 42     End
------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Perl has better debugging tools than PCRE, try `echo 123454321 | perl -Mre=debug -ne '/^((.)(?1)\2|.?)$/x'`. This gives not only some bytecode that is similar to PCRE's one, but it also shows each step, and the consumed and remaining parts of the input at each step:

```
Compiling REx "^((.)(?1)\2|.?)$"
Final program:
   1: BOL (2)
   2: OPEN1 (4)
   4:   BRANCH (15)
   5:     OPEN2 (7)
   7:       REG_ANY (8)
   8:     CLOSE2 (10)
  10:     GOSUB1[-8] (13)
  13:     REF2 (19)
  15:   BRANCH (FAIL)
  16:     CURLY {0,1} (19)
  18:       REG_ANY (0)
  19: CLOSE1 (21)
  21: EOL (22)
  22: END (0)
floating ""$ at 0..2147483647 (checking floating) anchored(BOL) minlen 0 
Guessing start of match in sv for REx "^((.)(?1)\2|.?)$" against "12321"
Found floating substr ""$ at offset 5...
Guessed: match at offset 0
Matching REx "^((.)(?1)\2|.?)$" against "12321"
   0 <> <12321>              |  1:BOL(2)
   0 <> <12321>              |  2:OPEN1(4)
   0 <> <12321>              |  4:BRANCH(15)
   0 <> <12321>              |  5:  OPEN2(7)
   0 <> <12321>              |  7:  REG_ANY(8)
   1 <1> <2321>              |  8:  CLOSE2(10)
   1 <1> <2321>              | 10:  GOSUB1[-8](13)
   1 <1> <2321>              |  2:    OPEN1(4)
   1 <1> <2321>              |  4:    BRANCH(15)
   1 <1> <2321>              |  5:      OPEN2(7)
   1 <1> <2321>              |  7:      REG_ANY(8)
   2 <12> <321>              |  8:      CLOSE2(10)
   2 <12> <321>              | 10:      GOSUB1[-8](13)
   2 <12> <321>              |  2:        OPEN1(4)
   2 <12> <321>              |  4:        BRANCH(15)
   2 <12> <321>              |  5:          OPEN2(7)
   2 <12> <321>              |  7:          REG_ANY(8)
   3 <123> <21>              |  8:          CLOSE2(10)
   3 <123> <21>              | 10:          GOSUB1[-8](13)
   3 <123> <21>              |  2:            OPEN1(4)
   3 <123> <21>              |  4:            BRANCH(15)
   3 <123> <21>              |  5:              OPEN2(7)
   3 <123> <21>              |  7:              REG_ANY(8)
   4 <1232> <1>              |  8:              CLOSE2(10)
   4 <1232> <1>              | 10:              GOSUB1[-8](13)
   4 <1232> <1>              |  2:                OPEN1(4)
   4 <1232> <1>              |  4:                BRANCH(15)
   4 <1232> <1>              |  5:                  OPEN2(7)
   4 <1232> <1>              |  7:                  REG_ANY(8)
   5 <12321> <>              |  8:                  CLOSE2(10)
   5 <12321> <>              | 10:                  GOSUB1[-8](13)
   5 <12321> <>              |  2:                    OPEN1(4)
   5 <12321> <>              |  4:                    BRANCH(15)
   5 <12321> <>              |  5:                      OPEN2(7)
   5 <12321> <>              |  7:                      REG_ANY(8)
                                                        failed...
   5 <12321> <>              | 15:                    BRANCH(19)
   5 <12321> <>              | 16:                      CURLY {0,1}(19)
                                                        REG_ANY can match 0 times out of 1...
   5 <12321> <>              | 19:                        CLOSE1(21)
                                                          EVAL trying tail ... 9d86dd8
   5 <12321> <>              | 13:                          REF2(19)
                                                            failed...
                                                        failed...
                                                      BRANCH failed...
   4 <1232> <1>              | 15:                BRANCH(19)
   4 <1232> <1>              | 16:                  CURLY {0,1}(19)
                                                    REG_ANY can match 1 times out of 1...
   5 <12321> <>              | 19:                    CLOSE1(21)
                                                      EVAL trying tail ... 9d86d70
   5 <12321> <>              | 13:                      REF2(19)
                                                        failed...
   4 <1232> <1>              | 19:                    CLOSE1(21)
                                                      EVAL trying tail ... 9d86d70
   4 <1232> <1>              | 13:                      REF2(19)
                                                        failed...
                                                    failed...
                                                  BRANCH failed...
   3 <123> <21>              | 15:            BRANCH(19)
   3 <123> <21>              | 16:              CURLY {0,1}(19)
                                                REG_ANY can match 1 times out of 1...
   4 <1232> <1>              | 19:                CLOSE1(21)
                                                  EVAL trying tail ... 9d86d08
   4 <1232> <1>              | 13:                  REF2(19)
                                                    failed...
   3 <123> <21>              | 19:                CLOSE1(21)
                                                  EVAL trying tail ... 9d86d08
   3 <123> <21>              | 13:                  REF2(19)
                                                    failed...
                                                failed...
                                              BRANCH failed...
   2 <12> <321>              | 15:        BRANCH(19)
   2 <12> <321>              | 16:          CURLY {0,1}(19)
                                            REG_ANY can match 1 times out of 1...
   3 <123> <21>              | 19:            CLOSE1(21)
                                              EVAL trying tail ... 9d86ca0
   3 <123> <21>              | 13:              REF2(19)
   4 <1232> <1>              | 19:              CLOSE1(21)
                                                EVAL trying tail ... 0
   4 <1232> <1>              | 13:                REF2(19)
   5 <12321> <>              | 19:                CLOSE1(21)
   5 <12321> <>              | 21:                EOL(22)
   5 <12321> <>              | 22:                END(0)
Match successful!
Freeing REx: "^((.)(?1)\2|.?)$"
```

As you can see, Perl first consumes all input recursing until `(.)` fails, then starts backtracking and trying the second branch from the alternation `.?` and the remainder of the first part `\2`, when that fails it backtracks, until it finally succeeds.

Comment: Why in this debug, there are six `OPEN1` but correspondingly eight `CLOSE1`? Should it not be six `CLOSE1` as well?

Answer (score 0):

Breakdown: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/lOZVQ))

```
$regex = <<<REGEX
/
^       #start of string
(       #start capture group 1
 (      #start capture group 2 
  .     #match any non-newline character
 )      #end capture group2
 (?1)   #repeat the expression of capture group 1
 \2     #match the character from capture group 2
 |      #or
 .?     #the middle character (if odd length input string) or no character (if even length input string)
)       #end capture group 1
$       #end of string
/x
REGEX;
```

Traversing `redder` (explanation doesn't include backtracking from unsatisfactory attempts by the regex engine):

1. Match start of the string

   ```
   ^((.)(?1)\2|.?)$
   ^
   ```
2. Get outer characters, and recurse middle characters using group 1 as subpattern:

   ```
   ^((.)(?1)\2|.?)$
      r      r
         ^^-> edde
   ```
3. Get outer characters, and recurse middle characters using group 1 as subpattern:

   ```
   ^((.)(?1)\2|.?)$
      e      e
         ^^-> dd
   ```
4. Get outer characters, and recurse middle characters using group 1 as subpattern:

   ```
   ^((.)(?1)\2|.?)$
      d      d
         ^^- (zero-width position)
   ```
5. Match the zero-width position at the middle of the string:

   ```
   ^((.)(?1)\2|.?)$
               ^^- (zero-width position)
   ```
6. Match end of the string:

   ```
   ^((.)(?1)\2|.?)$
                  ^
   ```

---

Traversing `kayak` (explanation doesn't include backtracking from unsatisfactory attempts by the regex engine):

1. Match start of the string

   ```
   ^((.)(?1)\2|.?)$
   ^
   ```
2. Get outer characters, and recurse middle characters using group 1 as subpattern:

   ```
   ^((.)(?1)\2|.?)$
      k      k
         ^^-> aya
   ```
3. Get outer characters, and recurse middle characters using group 1 as subpattern:

   ```
   ^((.)(?1)\2|.?)$
      a      a
         ^^-> y
   ```
4. Match the lone character at the middle of the string:

   ```
   ^((.)(?1)\2|.?)$
               y
   ```
5. Match end of the string:

   ```
   ^((.)(?1)\2|.?)$
                  ^
   ```